# SOA Suite 12c - oracle.tip.tools.ide.utils.xml.generator.instance.InstanceGenerationException

Tags: soa, oracle12c, weblogic12c, jdeveloper, bpel

I am trying to create a composite test case for my application. When I try to generate sample request/ response, I get an error in Jdeveloper.

Reported by logger:

> oracle.tip.tools.ide.utils.xml.generator.instance.InstanceGenerator
>   Nov 28, 2017 5:35:22 PM
>   oracle.tip.tools.ide.utils.xml.generator.instance.InstanceGenerator
>   generateInstance SEVERE: Error occurred while generating the sample
>   instance. null
>   oracle.tip.tools.ide.utils.xml.generator.instance.InstanceGenerationException:
>   Error occurred while generating the sample instance. null     at
>   oracle.tip.tools.ide.utils.xml.generator.instance.InstanceGenerator.generateInstance(InstanceGenerator.java:365)
>     at
>   oracle.tip.tools.ide.fabric.testgen.dialog.XMLInputPanel.generateXML(XMLInputPanel.java:589)
>     at
>   oracle.tip.tools.ide.fabric.testgen.dialog.XMLInputPanel.actionPerformed(XMLInputPanel.java:414)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)

Comment: Please answer this query..........

Answer (score 0):

This error is resolve if you check the xsd file if element **anytype format** defined.Please change that one into string format other format supported in xml.